# Ruby - Elegantly replace hash values with nested value (description)

Tags: ruby

The hash I'm working with has a hash  for it's values which always contains an ID, name, and description.  I am not interested in keeping the ID or name and just want to replace every hash value with its corresponding description.

**Code**

```
hsh['nested']['entries']['addr'] = hsh['nested']['entries']['addr']['description']
hsh['nested']['entries']['port'] = hsh['nested']['entries']['port']['description']
hsh['nested']['entries']['protocol'] = hsh['nested']['entries']['protocol']['description']
hsh['nested']['entries']['type'] = hsh['nested']['entries']['type']['description']
... (many more)
```

This works fine, but it is not very elegant--in reality, I have 20 entries/lines of code to get the job done.

**Structure of the hash value** (for `hsh['nested']['entries']['addr']`)

```
{ "id" => "27", "name" => "Instance", "description" => "**This is what I need.**" }
```

Taking the first line of code above as a sample, the end result would be the value of `hsh['nested']['entries']['addr']` becomes `**This is what I need.**`

What is an elegant way to achieve this?

Comment: Please adjust your sample code and data so it's runnable and it demonstrates the problem you're having. "[mcve]" describes how to ask. We need the minimal code demonstrating the problem, along with the minimum input data and your expected output. While we can cobble up data, it forces us to use different starting points which leads to inaccuracies and the potential for confusing answers. Remember, your question and our answers are an article to help future searchers find a similar solution, not just answer it for you.

Comment: Apologies, I'll review and correct this on Monday if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sub_hash = hsh['nested']['entries']
categories = %w{addr port protocol type}

categories.each do |category|
  sub_hash[category] = sub_hash[category]['description']
end
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll test on Monday and report back.

Answer (score 2):

```
hsh = { 'nested'=>
        { 'entries'=>
          { 
            'addr'=>{ "id" => "1", "description"=>"addr" },
            'port'=>{ "id" => "2", "description"=>"port" },
            'cats'=>{ "id" => "3", "description"=>"dogs" },
            'type'=>{ "id" => "4", "description"=>"type" }
          }
        }
      }

keys_to_replace = ["addr", "port", "type"]

hsh['nested']['entries'].tap { |h| keys_to_replace.each { |k| h[k]=h[k]["description"] }
  #=> { "addr"=>"addr",
  #     "port"=>"port",
  #     "cats"=>{"id"=>"3", "description"=>"dogs"},
  #     "type"=>"type"
  #   } 

hsh
  #=> {"nested"=>
  #     { "entries"=>
  #       { "addr"=>"addr",
  #         "port"=>"port",
  #         "cats"=>{"id"=>"3", "description"=>"dogs"},
  #         "type"=>"type"
  #       }
  #     } 
  #   }
```

Comment: Never used `tap` before, I'll review how this works soon and see which answer is the most robust.  Appreciate it.

Comment: You will find they are equally robust. The main difference is that `tap` returns the modified `hsh`, whereas @seph's answer does not. If embedded in a method, seph would have to add `hsh` as the last line. That difference is minor. Imo it comes down to personal preference, perhaps which method "reads" best.

Comment: I'll give this one to @seph only due to giving the underdog some points.  Clearly, you don't need more :).  Even so, this is a very helpful explanation and I understand the difference.  I will likely use your code in the future when I need to return the identical, altered hash.  In this case, I don't need to worry about rebuilding the hash.  So to be clear, if I use seph's answer within a method, I need to return the hash--got it.

Comment: Upvoted as the code you provided is definitely useful in certain circumstances.  @seph's is the cleanest to read and I'm writing code for future users who will need to come in and understand--they may not have THAT much Ruby background.  Thanks as usual Cary.   My least favorite part of SO is picking between 2 correct answers.